# dhcpd.conf DNS order is being reset after each cobbler sync

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dhcp, cobbler, dhcpd

I'm trying to switch the order of DNS servers that my clients machines use by editing the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file in cobbler. This was the settings before I attempted the change:

```
subnet 10.100.48.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 {
     option routers             10.100.48.53;
     option domain-name-servers 10.100.48.51, 10.100.51.205;
     option subnet-mask         255.255.252.0;
```

This is how I am updating the file (i.e. the DNS servers are switched around):

```
subnet 10.100.48.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 {
     option routers             10.100.48.53;
     option domain-name-servers 10.100.51.205, 10.100.48.51;
     option subnet-mask         255.255.252.0;
```

The problem is, whenever I run `cobbler sync` the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file reverts to the original state. How can I ensure this does not happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out how to resolve the issue for anyone who might come across this question.
I needed to update this file:

```
/etc/cobbler/dhcp.template
```

When you run `cobbler sync`, the dhcpd.conf file is generated from the info in the dhcp.template file. once I had updated this file everything worked as expected.